# Change bootstrap 4 button text in media breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Changing bootstrap button content on media breakpoint is adding content but not clearing previous content.

Say I have this button

```
<button type="button" class="mybutton btn btn-outline btn-sm">The Before</button>
```

I hit a breakpoint and change the button text

```
.mybutton:before {
  content: "The After";
}
```

The button result should be "The After" but instead it's "The AfterThe Before"

The rendered css is

```
<button type="button" class="mybutton btn btn-outline btn-sm">
  ::before
  The Before
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to hide the font size before changing content.

```
.nav-pills, .nav-link > a {
  font-size: 0 !important;
}
```